# Long execution time for indexed query in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

I am using Postgresql 9.2 and I am facing the problem with the index usage.

Consider a quite big table (124M records) with 2 columns: device_id, date.

*Device_id* is the id of the device that is saving data in this table.

*Date* is the timestamp. Device is generating about 50-2000 records daily.
I have an index on this table based on (date, device_id).

When I am executing the query:

```
select date 
from table 
where device_id = 1 
order by date asc 
limit 1
```

it works perfectly fine (executed in ms) **when there are records in this table for device_id == 1**.

The problem starts when there are no records for device_id == 1.
*Explain* command shows that the planner is using the index, but it takes minutes (sometimes almost an hour) to execute.

The query plan for the first situation (records exist in the table):

```
"Limit  (cost=0.00..3.87 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Output: date"
"  Buffers: shared hit=5"
"  ->  Index Scan using i_table_deviceid_date on public.table  (cost=0.00..1406868.86 rows=363300 width=8) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Output: date"
"        Index Cond: ((table.device_id)::text = '354330030970803'::text)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=5"
"Total runtime: 0.039 ms"
```

The query plan for the second situation (no records yet/already):

```
"Limit  (cost=0.00..3.99 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2067070.604..2067070.604 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Output: date"
"  Buffers: shared hit=41587 read=141992 written=564"
"  ->  Index Scan using i_table_deviceid_date on public.table  (cost=0.00..446995.42 rows=112010 width=8) (actual time=2067070.602..2067070.602 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Output: date"
"        Index Cond: ((table.device_id)::text = '354330030957453'::text)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=41587 read=141992 written=564"
"Total runtime: 2067070.620 ms"
```

The possible reasons why there are no records for the particular device_id are two:

1. all data were removed
2. first data for this devide_id were not saved yet

Any help will be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Please add the datadefinitions (includig PK,FK,indexes)  in code, not as text.

Comment: "*Date is the timestamp*" now that is one confusing naming convention.

Comment: You definitely need to show the explain plans for the two queries.

Comment: `I have an index on this table based on (date, device_id).` you could need an index on `(device_id, date)` **(and 'date' is a bad name for a column)**

Comment: @DavidAldridge I edited the question, adding the explains plans

Comment: @wildplasser you may be right, I will try this as well. Naming convention is only an example to simplify the problem :)

Comment: Try reindexing the table??

Comment: the output of `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` would be more helpful

Comment: @user3266991 do you think it is necessary to reindex the table whenever I remove records? My understanding was that the index is being updated while removing data. Furthermore, it looks like it is random :( sometimes I remove a lot of records and the querey is executed quickly too.

Comment: `((device_id)::text = '1'::text)` Now, **why** is this casted to text at both sides?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated the analyze output.

Comment: Looks like your statistics aren't up to date. Does this change when you run `analyze` on the table in question? I also second wildplasser question: Is your query **really** using `where device_id = 1` or are you maybe using `where device_id = '1'`?  (the first compares a number, the second compares a string)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I am running analyze right now. According to your second question - as I stated above, I modified the table structure to simplify the problem. Originally, the device_id is character varying (20)

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column? You might also want to consider upgrading to 9.4 - or even wait a bit and then go directly to 9.5 - both have many performance improvements over 9.2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the reason of that choice is the application logic (old logic). The device ID is the device factory ID which isn't always the number. Right now we are trying to modify that, creating our own mapping table with the devices and use the PK instead of the factory id.

Upgrading to 9.4 is also in progress. We already did that on testing environment.

Comment: @wildplasser it is not casted by us. It is the output from PGAdmin, I guess the output is formatted like that by the app.
The query was: `select date from table where device_id = '1'` (as I stated above, orginally, the device_id in the table is character varying.

Comment: Shouldn't you have an index on device_id, date rather than date, device_id? I'd expect it to lead to index lookups. Now the index is fully scanned which works fine if you will limit the output to one record because it can stop as soon as it finds one but scanning will need to continue when none is found until the end of the index.

Comment: @Tunker: please dont lie. The query in your question says: `where device_id = 1`. Without any quoting.

Comment: @wildplasser please read the comments too. The query in my question is not a real one. It is pseudocode to present the problem. The outputs are from the real database where the device_id is the character varying. I explain that in my comment to a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `The query in my question is not a real one. It is pseudocode ...` Sorry, I don't optimize pseudocode. Go away. **plonk**